# How to merge 2 websites into 1 website with 2 storeviews

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, store-view, websites

Before I continue to ask my question I would like to state that I am aware of the troubles I'm about to run into if I actually true to accomplish this. Yet, I want to be sure to that I checked all ins and outs so my answer to our client can be accurate and reliable. I think we've all been there.

In this case we have 1 Magento installation(1.9.0.1) which has 2 websites. One for Germany (.de) and one for Dutch visitors (.eu).

Both have just one store-view. The request we received is that our customer wants to have one system, containing one website that has 2 store-views.

Now I can create a new store-view in an existing website and connect that to the right design package but then: products, category's, attributes: all have to be 'moved' from their current website to the other one. I believe this is going to be manual labor, because moving them using sql queries is going to be tricky, dangerous and time consuming.

So, what are your idea's and suggestions in this situation? Do it manually or is there a way to do this quick and easy without a lot of risks?

Thanks for your help!

p.s. the current website uses a theme that is no longer available for updates, just as a couple of modules installed. Just adding this because I want you to have as much information as possible.

Answer (score 0):

> Magento manages categories and products from Website label

So, if you create **a new store-view** under **current website** then you **don't need to assign products and categories separately for new store-view**.Vales for **products & categories** are taken from  **Default Scope**.

**Note that:** `Just need to do Magento indexing properly after creating new store view`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but that is not very useful when looking at descriptions and meta's for example. They are filled with Dutch content for one website and with German content for the second. Default scope would mess up the descriptions and I have to set all the values again for each product. That's my biggest fear.